# Update an Array of Objects Using Form - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a form with 3 inputs, which the user will insert the hex value for colors.

I need to receive these values and to update one property of objects of an Array. This update will be just for front-end purpose, no Json access or server is running.

Form.html

```
<form name="colorform" class="row col-md-offset-1" ng-submit="update(name, data)">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Color A</label>
            <input name="main" ng-model="colors.main" class="form-control">    
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Color B</label>
            <input name="locker" ng-model="colors.locker" class="form-control">    
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Color C</label>
            <input name="path" ng-model="colors.path" class="form-control">    
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Save
        </button>
         <a href="#/" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
        <hr>
    </div>
</form>
```

The Array of Objects:

```
$scope.colors = [
        {name: "main", color: "white"},
        {name: "locker", color: "black"},
        {name: "path", color: "yellow"}
    ];
```

And the update function:

```
$scope.update = function(name, data) {
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.colors.length; i++) {
       if ($scope.colors[i].name == name) {
           $scope.colors[i].color = data;
           break;
       }
   }
 }
```

I intent to update the `color` property. The goal is to reflect in a html element, that uses this function on Controller:

```
$scope.style = function ($index) {       
        return {
            "height" : "15px",
            "width" : "15px",
            "border" : "1px solid #CCC",
            "background-color": $scope.colors[1].color,
            "float": "left"
        }
    }
```

And on HTML that displays:

```
<div ng-style="boardStyle" class="board">
  <div ng-repeat="tile in getNumber(tiles) track by $index" 
    ng-style="style($index)"></div>
</div>
```

But... Nothing happens. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is data, name in your update function?

Comment: I thought that name is "name" and data is "color". But I think there is some confusion...

Comment: do you want to update the colors $scope/object? here is a simple solution without update function. [see here](https://plnkr.co/edit/m7uHderqtNIQ2MgrW8Ji?p=preview)

Comment: @sahed sawon I'm not sure if it will work. Sorry for lack of information, then I complete my question with other informations. Please, see it above.

Comment: @pegla provide a good solution. hope it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can improve your code a bit, first problem you have is that your input models point to wrong thing. Let's create good model for your data:

```
$scope.colors = {
    main: {
      color: "white"
    },
    locker: {
      color: "black"
    },
    path: {
      color: "yellow"
    }
  };
```

After this let's fix your getNumber function to return keys of an object in array:

```
$scope.getNumber = function(tiles){
  return Object.keys($scope.colors);
}
```

and at the end fix your style function to take key and not $index, which is very bad in my opinion, so:

```
$scope.style = function (key) {       
        return {
            "height" : "15px",
            "width" : "15px",
            "border" : "1px solid #CCC",
            "background-color": $scope.colors[key].color,
            "float": "left"
        }
    }
```

And at the end we need to do some small changes in html to adjust few things 
in your code like input fields pointing to correct model:

```
<input name="main" ng-model="colors.main.color" class="form-control">
<input name="locker" ng-model="colors.locker.color" class="form-control">
<input name="path" ng-model="colors.path.color" class="form-control">
```

and repeat divs:

```
<div ng-repeat="tile in getNumber(tiles) track by $index" ng-style="style(tile)"></div>
```

If you decide you actually want functionality of save button to trigger change, you can just duplicate colors object and just name it $scope.colors2 - change ng-model on inputs to point to colors2 and inside your update function just update colors with colors2 $scope.colors = $scope.colors2

Here's fiddle to show how it works:

https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/j392Lvdp/5/

Also here's fiddle with save button working:

https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/j392Lvdp/6/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any work with the server.
You don't really need a form/submit() to update properties.
You are using **ng-model to access array of object** which automatically updates the properties.

```
   <form name="colorform" class="row col-md-offset-1" ng-submit="update()">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Color A</label>
            <input name="main" ng-model="colors[0].color" class="form-control">    
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Color B</label>
            <input name="locker" ng-model="colors[1].color" class="form-control">    
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Color C</label>
            <input name="path" ng-model="colors[2].color" class="form-control">    
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Save
        </button>
         <a href="#/" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
        <hr>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
  <div ng-repeat="tile in colors track by $index" ng-style="style($index)"></div>
</div>
```

Here is your array of objects just as you need:

```
  $scope.colors = [
        {name: "main", color: "white"},
        {name: "locker", color: "black"},
        {name: "path", color: "yellow"}
    ];
```

Your update function if want one:

```
  $scope.update = function() {
    alert("Colors have been updated!");
  }
```

And your style function:

```
  $scope.style = function(key) {
    return {
      "height": "15px",
      "width": "15px",
      "border": "1px solid #CCC",
      "background-color": $scope.colors[key].color,
      "float": "left"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there any way for "persisting" these changes to another view (when I click on back button of the form)? I think about Local Storage to store this array of objects. Is it possible?